# Why wp_update_user doesn't update user_activation_key on users with apostrophes in their email?

Tags: login, password

Wordpress currently allows apostrophes in email addresses. However, when a user with an apostrophe in their email tries to perform a password reset, the user_activation_key is invalid.

It looks as if user_activation_keys can be generated for users with apostrophes in their email, but the key cannot be stored in the wp_user table.

I've tried manually setting user_activation_keys for users with apostrophes by calling wp_update_user to no avail.

Why is this? Is there a way to bypass the get_password_reset_key for users with apostrophe emails?

Comment: This sounds like a bug you should report to the [WordPress Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/) please if you haven't already. And please edit a link to the trac ticket into your question.

Comment: (I'd guess the problem is filtering or bad-escaping for the apostrophe, which is a string terminator in SQL. If you want to solve this yourself I'd start there.)

Comment: I came across this issue again so I created a bug report on the [Wordpress Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/56090). Thanks for the advice, @Rup